# How to run the assembly I got from clang++ test.cpp -S?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, linker-errors, clang++

So I got the assembly code of a C++ program by the `clang++ test.cpp -S`

Now I have the test.s which is the assembly ... now how to run this in an Android (ARM)?

I tried as `test.s -o test.o` then `ld test.o -o test` ... but it gives me an error in the ld part ...[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gQgl.jpg)

Comment: You have to link against the `c++` standard library. Also why turn it into assembly and then link manually, can't you compile it all the way with `clang++`?

Comment: the simple way is `clang++ test.s` to assemble it, and link it with the right libraries.  Use `clang++ -v test.s` to show which args were passed to `ld` by the `clang++` front-end command.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text please!  [Edit] your question to contain the error messages as text instead of a picture.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't want to use the clang++ command ... so i did clang++ -v test.s to see the args or something ... I really don't get it ... is the args inside the double quotation part ?  could you tell me which part is the args and exactly what do i have to write ? like ```as test.s -o test.o``` then ```ld test.o args_here -o test``` ... is this the way or something different ?

Answer (score 1):

`clang++ -v test.cpp` to see what argument it passes to ld .
then copy paste
`ld args -o test`
It worked, thanks